# scrollview does not work properly

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

i want to have an scroll view at one of my activities(I have two activity in my app) I know I have to add "Scrollview" tag to the top of my XML and put the Linear layout in it,but it does not work at all.i have read many on StackOverflow but it did not help. here is the XML code.

```
<ScrollView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton3"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton4"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton5"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/mainphotos">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_imageButton6"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/breakingbads"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/topMovies_textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Top 10 Serials"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textColor="@color/textcolor"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

there is one LinearLayout that contains many inner LinearLayouts so the outer LinearLayout is the child of the scroll view.
Note that every inner layout contains a single view so i left it to be horizontal by default(exept the most inner ones that contains two view and i want it to set them horizantally thats beacuase i did not set orientation)

Comment: don't use scroll view as a main layout

Comment: Set the first LinearLayout height to wrap_content

Comment: Why you do not specify the orientation of the most `LinearLayout`s?

Comment: with setting the first LinearLayouts height to wrap_content nothing happened

Comment: Yes, @Demigod is correct. Attribute `orientation` of `LinearLayout` is strongly required (at least Android Studio throws compilation error).

Comment: Agreed with @Demigod and nick. If you don't specify orientation to linear layout it will take horizontal by default.

Comment: dear @nick every inner layout contains a single view except the most inner that contains two view(imageButton and Textview) and by setting orientation to that layout nothing happend